# How to improve tests with a myriad of switch statements?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need to test whether data returned from a search is correct. Several operators can be used for search (term, prefix, wildcard etc.), several fields can be searched (firstName, lastName, email, address etc.), and of course any search parameter (''John'', ''Smith'', ''john.smith@gmail.com'') can be entered. In my tests I've ended up with a lot of switch statements and am wondering if this is acceptable?

Here is a sample test, for the operator 'term' (all other tests look basically like this, too):

```
[Theory]
[InlineData("term", "firstName", "John")]
[InlineData("term", "email", "@gmail")]
public void Contains_String(string _operator, string field, string value)
{
  string response = FakeSearch.GetResponse(_operator, field, value);

  var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Rootobject>(response);

  foreach (var employee in result.Hits.HitsArray)
  {
    switch (field)
    {
      case "firstName":
        Assert.True(employee.Source.FirstName.Contains(value, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase));
        break;
      case "lastName":
        Assert.True(employee.Source.LastName.Contains(value, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase));
        break;
      case "phone":
        Assert.True(employee.Source.Phone.Contains(value);
        break;
      case "email":
        Assert.True(employee.Source.Email.Contains(value, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase));
        break;
    }
  }
}

public static class FakeSearch
{
  public static string GetResponse(string _operator, string field, string value)
  {
    string query = GenerateQuery(_operator, field, value);

    return GetData(query);
  }

  public static string GenerateQuery(string _operator, string field, string value)
  {
    QueryRootobject searchObj = new QueryRootobject();
    searchObj.Query = new Query();
    searchObj.Query.Bool = new Bool();
    searchObj.Query.Bool.Must = new Must[1];
    searchObj.Query.Bool.Must[0] = new Must();

    switch (_operator)
    {
      case "term":
        searchObj.Query.Bool.Must[0].Term = new Term();
        switch (field)
        {
          case "firstName":
            searchObj.Query.Bool.Must[0].Term.FirstName = value;
            break;
          case "lastName":
            searchObj.Query.Bool.Must[0].Term.LastName = value;
            break;
          case "phone":
            searchObj.Query.Bool.Must[0].Term.Phone = value;
            break;
          case "email":
            searchObj.Query.Bool.Must[0].Term.Email = value;
            break;
        }
        break;
      case "prefix":
        searchObj.Query.Bool.Must[0].Prefix = new Prefix();
        switch (field)
        {
          case "firstName":
            searchObj.Query.Bool.Must[0].Prefix.FirstName = value;
            break;
          case "lastName":
            searchObj.Query.Bool.Must[0].Prefix.LastName = value;

            // and so on
        }
      case "wildcard":
        // and so on
}
```

Can/should this be improved in some way? All the switch statements seem like way too much. Perhaps they're okay in the test, but could the `GenerateQuery` method be improved? And if so, how?

Comment: ["Programmers" hasn't been called "Programmers" in over three years](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8267/1352), and this type of question was always off-topic there for the same reasons that it is off-typic here. [Please, only recommend other sites if you *completely* understand their scope.](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7183/1352)

Comment: @JörgWMittag My mistake on the naming, but if I don't suggest an alternative what would be the proper response? Just vote to close without explanation?  Just trying to be helpful here, personally I prefer this type of question to be in SO.

Answer (score 2):

You could create a table of delegates, I suppose.

```
var map = new Dictionary<string,Func<Employee,string>>
{
    { "firstName", e => e.Source.FirstName },
    { "lastName",  e => e.Source.LastName },
    { "phone",     e => e.Source.Phone },
    { "email",     e => e.Source.Email }
};
```

Then you could ditch the switch/case statement and just use the delegate.

```
var func = map[field];
foreach (var employee in result.Hits.HitsArray)
{
    Assert.True(func(employee).Contains(value, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase));
}
```